# How to read a text file in several step with awk

Tags: awk, text-processing

I have a text file like this:

```
R 3
W 1
W 2
W 3
R 2
R 5
W 3
W 6
R 2
R 5
```

I want to check whole of the file when I see `W` in `$1`. `GAP` is a initial integer (in this case is 6) and I wanna replace `$2=GAP` by `GAP+1`

```
first W; GAP=6;
R 3
W 1 <- first W
W 2
W 3
R 2
R 5
W 3
W 6 <- GAP
R 2
R 5
```

in step 1, I want to apply this modification:

```
R 3
W 1
W 2
W 3
R 2
R 5
W 3
W 7 <- 6+1
R 2
R 5
```

`GAP` is decrease by one and second W has been seen.
second `W`; `GAP=5;`

```
R 3
W 1
W 2 <- second W
W 3
R 2
R 5 <- GAP
W 3
W 7
R 2
R 5 <- GAP
```

In the same way the output of step 2 is:

```
R 3
W 1
W 2
W 3
R 2
R 6 <- 5+1
W 3
W 7
R 2
R 6 <- 5+1
```

step 3:

```
R 3
W 1
W 2
W 3 <- third W
R 2
R 6
W 3
W 7
R 2
R 6
```

step 4:

```
R 3
W 1
W 2
W 3
R 2
R 6
W 3 <- fourth W
W 7
R 2
R 6
```

step 5: last W and last output

```
R 3
W 1
W 2
W 3
R 2
R 6
W 3
W 7 <- fifth W
R 3 <- 2+1
R 6
```

The output file must be similar to this:

```
R 3
W 1
W 2
W 3
R 2
R 6
W 3
W 7
R 3
R 6
```

I have tried this code but does not work correctly:

```
awk 'BEGIN{GAP=6}{if($1=="W") {if($2==GAP) $2=GAP+1; GAP--;} print $0}' file.txt
```

Comment: Suggestion:  If the file is small you can keep the values in an array (or two) and operate the logic on array elements by iterating until done.

Answer (score 0):

You should break with the idea of making multiple passes.
First of all, awk is not designed to make multiple passes across the same file; awk is not an editor.
Secondly, the problem becomes a lot simpler when you try to solve it in a single pass.

Notice that every line is incremented *at most* once.
Furthermore, a line is only incremented if its `$2` value plus the number of `W` lines above it is greater than or equal to 7.

This is pretty straightforward in AWK.
Since this is clearly a homework assignment, I will leave the implementation to you.

(Of course I *did* try it myself; and it works.)